# how to create a query with multiple tables in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want to create a query with multiple tables

the query that i need is:

```
SELECT orders.user_id, orderitem.product_id, orderitem.orderItem_quantity, product.product_price, product.product_imgPath,product.product_name 
FROM orderitem, orders, product, users
WHERE orders.user_id = '$_Session[user_id]'
AND orderitem.product_id = product.product_id
AND orderitem.order_id = orders.order_id
AND orders.order_status = 1
```

and i try these codes:

1:

```
$cartProducts = DB::table('orderitem')
        ->join('product','product.product_id','=','orderitem.product_id')
        ->join('orders','orders.order_id','=','orderitem.order_id')
        ->where('orders.order_status','=','Waiting')
        ->where('orders.user_id','=',$userId)
        ->select('orderitem.*','orders.*','product.*','users.*')
        ->get();
```

The error that i get is:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'users'
```

2:

```
$cartProducts = DB::table('orderitem','orders','products','users')
            ->select('orderitem.*','orders.*','products.*','users.*')
            ->where('orders.user_id','=',$userId)
            ->where('orderitem.product_id','=','product.product_id')
            ->where('orderitem.order_id','=','orders_id')
            ->where('order_status','=','Waiting')
            ->get();
```

The error that i get is:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'orders'
```

And i know that i can't use multiple parameter for table function

Comment: Do the users and orders tables exists? Also, you can use relationships to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Use laravel relationships https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

First, in your `User` model do:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Images'); //make sure your images table has user_id column
    }
}
```

And then in your `Image` table model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Image extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Now in your controller:

```
$data = App\Post::user(1)->with('images');
return view('view_name', ["data" => $data]);
```

Your view:

```
@foreach($data->images as $image)
    <img src="{{ $image->url }}">
@endforeach
```